# Is 8ball pool of miniclip haram?

Tags: game, legal

Assalamualaikum my dear sisters and brothers. i have a question regarding 8 ball pool from miniclip. its like a virtual game of pool but players stack up virtual gamemoney and whosoever wins takes it. iknow this form would not be haram ( as i read a similar question before) but some players buy pool coins for real money and sometime these pool coins can be earned by the player!
please inform me about the second issue please thankyou in advance

Comment: I don't like the idea of gambling in any form... If it is even allowed to do so with virtual currency or points, i think it will surely lead to the real gambling.

Answer (score 2):

Wa'alaikumussalam,

Any currency that can't be used to trade for real goods are considered as virtual values, like points and marks. They are not treated as valuables and therefore are not bound to the laws of real valuables.

Even when the purchase of those virtual values are done with real money, but the virtual value it self are worthless. It is good to note that purchasing worthless values is a waste of money. And our beloved prophets Muhammad (peace be upon him) would not like us doing that.

Islam is about "salam", which means gain peace through [taqwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqwa).

We should check our every act, so to obey Allah's commands. We should never simulate (even on virtual world) any act of doing what Allah has forbid us to do so, like gambling, cheating, stealing, and other haram doings. Yes, even on virtual world.

So to maintain our soul at cleansed state of taqwa.

Comment: Worthless values can't be changed to real values. Once it can, they are not considered as worthless values anymore and therefore are bound to laws of real money.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and the stack exchange model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help]!

Comment: Miniclip sells coins for real cash, but only few buys that, so now what can we say??

Comment: @Ramanujan if that is the case. Then "Miniclip coins" should be bound to the laws of real values.